# Remove numbers and user's stop words from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I would like to know how to remove some variables from a dataset, specifically numbers and list of strings. For example.

```
    Test      Num
0   bam       132
1   -         65
2   creation  47
3   MAN       32
4   41        831
... ... ...
460 Luchino   21
461 42 4126   7
462 finger    43
463 washing   1
```

I would like to have something like

```
    Test      Num
0   bam       132
2   creation  47
... ... ...
460 Luchino   21
462 finger    43
463 washing   1
```

where I removed (manually) MAN (it should be included in a list of strings, like a stop word), `-`, and numbers.

I have tried with isdigit but it is not working so I am sure that there are errors in my code:

```
df['Text'].where(~df['Text'].str.isdigit())
```

and for my stop words:

```
my_stop=['MAN','-']
df['Text'].apply(lambda lst: [x for x in lst if x in my_stop])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter you could use `.loc`

```
df = df.loc[~df.Text.str.isdigit() & ~df.Text.isin(['MAN']), :]
```

`.where(cond, other)` returns a dataframe or series of the same shape as self, but keeps the original values where `cond` is true and replaces with `other` where it is false.
Read more in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Comment: Thanks RichieV. May I ask you how to extend to a list, rather than only a single word (e.g. MAN)? I have many words that I would like to remove from there

Comment: Create your list and code `... ~df.Text.isin(unwanted_list) ....`

Comment: @still_learning please note I was mistaken in the behavior of `.where`, it is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

hi you should try this code :

```
 df[df['Text']!='MAN']
```